# Spring security 3.1.4 : Is role hierarchy working with taglib authorize/authentication?

Tags: spring-security, hierarchy, roles, taglib

I re-post an old question, because i'm stucked with that...The question is expressed in the title...

Spring security 3.1.4 : Is role hierarchy working with  taglib authorize/authentication ?

If someone have any ideas to debug , it would be great !

Thanks

[The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387228/spring-security-taglib-authorize-authentication-are-not-working-with-role-hierar)