# sec:authorize doesn't work in spring security 3.2 and jsf

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

When I put some tags like this within my page:
user and admin will display at runtime anyway?
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.3.RELEASE
I have 2 folders(Admin and User) 
Also test with use-expressions="true" 
Did not the result! 
I used mysql 
table(users and user_roles) ...

```
<sec:authorize access="ROLE_ADMIN">
        <div> test Admin</div>
    </sec:authorize> 
    <sec:authorize access="ROLE_USER">
        <div> test User</div>
    </sec:authorize>
            or
  <sec:authorize  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" >
        <h:outputText value="Admin"/>
    </sec:authorize> 
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" >
        <h:outputText value="User"/>
    </sec:authorize>
```

Security.xml

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  >
        <intercept-url pattern="/Admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
         ...
 </http>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To use the Spring Security Facelets Tag Library you'll need to create a .taglib.xml file and register it in web.xml.

Create the file /WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Next, register the above file taglib in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now you are ready to use the tag library in your views. You can use the authorize tag to include nested content conditionally:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

    <sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

</ui:composition>
```

You can also use one of several EL functions in the rendered or other attribute of any JSF component:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

    <!-- Rendered only if user has all of the listed roles -->
    <h:outputText value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rendered="#{sec:areAllGranted('ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR')}"/>

    <!-- Rendered only if user does not have any of the listed roles -->
    <h:outputText value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rendered="#{sec:areNotGranted('ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR')}"/>

    <!-- Rendered only if user has any of the listed roles -->
    <h:outputText value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rendered="#{sec:areAnyGranted('ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR')}"/>

    <!-- Rendered only if user has access to given HTTP method/URL as defined in Spring Security configuration -->
    <h:outputText value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rendered="#{sec:isAllowed('/secured/foo', 'POST')}"/>

</ui:composition>
```

Tested on :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```