# Spring Security JSP Tags <sec:authorize access="hasRole('')"> not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jsp-tags

We are trying to implement some functionality to our web app. We are using Spring Framework v4.1.1 and Spring Security v3.1.7 for a Web App. We are using a custom authentication provider for our authentication process, everything works fine, but when we try to hide some content for a specific role in a page using the JSP tag from Spring Security it doesn't work.

Here is our security-conf.xml:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginerroneo"
        default-target-url="/seleccionar-empresa" always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/salir"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.grupo.seguridad.acceso.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceAdapater"/>
```

When we use this tag `<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>`  in our Page we got
[VENDEDOR, ADMINISTRADOR] wich is correct.

but when we tried to hide some content of a page using the tag:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMINISTRADOR')">
   <button class="btn btn-small btnGuardar" href="#dlgGuardar" data-toggle="modal">
      <i class="icon-hdd"></i> <strong>Una Opcion</strong>
    </button>
</sec:authorize>
```

It does not work.

We don't know what we are doing wrong.

Comment: May be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/26416548/3587592

Comment: That looks like it should definitely work.  I'm using spring security 3.2.5 on our current project and have the security tags working as you've described.  It's not a whitespace issue at play here is it (space before the role name ADMINISTRADOR)?

Comment: By default, roles should be named 'ROLE_*'. In the past I found that string hardcoded in the source code of Spring.

Comment: ADMINISTRADOR or ADMINISTRATOR?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ADMINISTRADOR">
    <button class="btn btn-small btnGuardar" href="#dlgGuardar" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="icon-hdd"></i> <strong>Una Opcion</strong>
        </button>
    </security:authorize>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It worked for me. I was struggling with hasRole('XXX') method.

Comment: ifAnyGranted is deprecated, one more thing I faced is, I stored User & Authorities then in my case I had to use "hasAuthority('admin')" or "hasAnyAuthority('admin', 'user')"

Answer (score 1):

I´m using Spring Security 4.2 and couldnt use the hasRole method...
But this code works for me:

```
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
you are an admin!
<security:authorize>
```

Comment: Using spring security 5 - this suggestion worked for me,